# How to dynamicallly add, delete node in list using onclick javascript

Tags: javascript

i want 2 images beside each folder.1st image, on clicking which its sub folder can be  created.2nd image, on clicking which folder itself with all its subfolder gets deleted

Here is my code..It can create subfolders but can't delete. I am new to javascript ...help me

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Javascript Directory code</title>

<style>
ul 
{
list-style-image:url('closed.gif');
}
</style>


</head>

<body>
<ul>
    <li onClick="myFunction.call(this, event)" id="root">Root</li>
</ul>


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function myFunction(e)
{
    e.stopPropagation();

    var id=prompt("Enter Folder id");
    if (id != '' && id != null)
    {
        var val=prompt("Enter Folder name");
    }
    if (id != '' && id != null && val !='' && val !=null) 
    {
        var ulnode=document.createElement("UL"); //new ul<br>
        var node=document.createElement("LI"); //new li<br>
        node.id = id;//set id of new li <br>
        node.onclick = myFunction;//set onclick event of new li<br> 

        var textnode=document.createTextNode(val);//li value<br>
        node.appendChild(textnode);// new li + li value<br>
        ulnode.appendChild(node);// ul + li value

        this.appendChild(ulnode);
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't add HTML code in your javascript code and css. That might trouble the code in the first place.

Comment: sir new to stackoverflow...kindly check my code here http://jsfiddle.net/tzPcw/1/

Comment: I thought this was your live code, so. Alright, can you give me some more information what you are trying to do? What is the folder and image in your code? And what for is the prompt function?

Comment: I want to create a directory structure dynamically li.2 icons just before directory name or li value.1St icon is a + sign on clicking which,you can create its subfolder,nested li. 2nd icon is - sign on clicking which folder with its subfolders get deleted. prompt wants user input for folder name or li value and li id  as folder id. help me i am new to javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may work:

```
        function myFunction(e)
        {
            e.stopPropagation();

            var id=prompt("Enter Folder id");
            if (id != '' && id != null)
            {
                var val=prompt("Enter Folder name");
            }
            if (id != '' && id != null && val !='' && val !=null) 
            {
                var ulnode=document.createElement("UL"); //new ul<br>
                var node=document.createElement("LI"); //new li<br>
                node.id = id;//set id of new li <br>
                node.onclick = myFunction;//set onclick event of new li<br>
                var anc=document.createElement("A"); //new li<br>
                anc.innerHTML = "---";
                anc.onclick = deleteNode;
                node.appendChild(anc);// new li + li value<br>);// new li + li value<br>

                var textnode=document.createTextNode(val);//li value<br>
                node.appendChild(textnode);// new li + li value<br>
                ulnode.appendChild(node);// ul + li value

                this.appendChild(ulnode);
            }
        }
        function deleteNode(e){
            e.stopPropagation();
            var caller = e.target || e.srcElement;
            var childToRemove = caller.parentNode.parentNode;
            childToRemove.parentNode.removeChild(childToRemove);
        }
```

Comment: this function is already called         
                anc.onclick = deleteNode;

Answer (score 0):

If you were to be using jQuery, you could use `$('#id-of-folder').remove();` in a function to remove it from the DOM.

Comment: how to make link on which user can click to delete...please see  output of current code here http://jsfiddle.net/tzPcw/1/